# Bing web search API to search only specific sites

Tags: c#, api, search, bots, bing

I'm using Bing web search API for getting articles about health in my Bot. How can I specify in the API which sites(urls) to search? Because sometimes it searches irrelevant sites, like wiki or wikipedia which I don't want to use. I've tried with site: parameter in API but it only gets the first site and ignores the rest urls.
Here is the API which I use now:
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=site:cdc.gov/ NOT site:wikipedia.org/" +url+ "&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate"